# LazyLoadInit exception with Spring + Spring JPA data + hibernate

Tags: spring, jpa, lazy-loading, spring-data-jpa

I can't figure this out. Am getting **"Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.sandy.domain.Location.items, no session or session was closed"** 
I understand that session is closed but tx:annotation-driver @Transactional should ensure an open session. It works fine with EAGER fetching. Oh and yea - this is by apress pro spring 3 examples.

But maybe I don't get the concept here - I mean while I am debugging "getFirst()" in SomeService I can see all the items in the collection but once return hits - LazyInit exception is thrown...

```
package org.sandy.main;

    import org.sandy.domain.Item;
    import org.sandy.domain.Location;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service(value = "main")
public class EntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService ss;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:*-beans.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        EntryPoint entryPoint = (EntryPoint) ctx.getBean("main");

        Item item = new Item();
        Location location = new Location();

        item.setLocation(location);
        location.getItems().add(item);

        entryPoint.getSs().save(location);

        System.out.println(entryPoint.getSs().findFirst());

        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    public SomeService getSs() {
        return ss;
    }

    public void setSs(SomeService ss) {
        this.ss = ss;
    }
}
```

and the service

```
package org.sandy.main;

import org.sandy.domain.Item;
import org.sandy.domain.Location;
import org.sandy.repo.ItemRepo;
import org.sandy.repo.LocationRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowire;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service(value = "ss")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepo itemRepo;
    @Autowired
    private LocationRepo locationRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Location location) {
        locationRepo.save(location);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Item> findFirst() {
        System.out.println("ONE");
        Iterable<Location> it = locationRepo.findAll();
        System.out.println("TWO");
        Location l = it.iterator().next();
        System.out.println("THREE");
        List<Item> r = l.getItems();
        return r;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Iterable finAll() {
        return locationRepo.findAll();
    }

    public void setItemRepo(ItemRepo itemRepo) {
        this.itemRepo = itemRepo;
    }

    public void setLocationRepo(LocationRepo locationRepo) {
        this.locationRepo = locationRepo;
    }
}
```

and location repo

```
package org.sandy.repo;

import org.sandy.domain.Location;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface LocationRepo extends CrudRepository<Location, Long> {
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Locations")
public class Location extends Entry {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "location")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

package org.sandy.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Items")
public class Item extends Entry {
    private Location location;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn()
    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

And the all mighty xml bean config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.sandy.domain" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.sandy.repo" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.sandy" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Does your `Item` class have a `toString()` method?

Comment: Yes, in this example no - it's just for show and tell.

Comment: It's actually relevant, can you post it?

Comment: @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Item{" +
    "state=" + state +
    ", sellPrice=" + sellPrice +
    ", vendorPrice=" + vendorPrice +
    ", dateSold=" + dateSold +
    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
    ", ART='" + ART + '\'' +
    ", location=" + location +
    "} " + super.toString();
 }
}

Supper class is "@MappedSuperclass" and contains "id" and "version" both Long

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code

```
System.out.println(entryPoint.getSs().findFirst());
```

is equivalent to

```
/* 1 */ SomeService ss = entryPoint.getSs();
/* 2 */ List<Item> items = ss.findFirst(); // Session opens and closes for @Transactional 
/* 3 */ String toPrint = items.toString(); // no more Session
/* 4 */ System.out.println(toPrint);
```

So you can see that the `Session` boundary is only wrapping the `findFirst()` call. If you're loading your entities lazily, then on line 3, the elements in `items` are not initialized. When you try to call `toString()` inside `List#toString()` which calls `toString()` on each element, you will get your `LazyInitializationException`.

You should fully initialize your entities before you use them. That has to be done within Session boundaries.

Comment: I had a misunderstanding on how LAZY loading is suppose to work - I imagined that it will fetch all of the foreign records on demand after a transaction whenever I want, turns out not.

Comment: @xe I don't know if you are planning to bring this to a web environment, but there are things you can do so that the session wraps all of your logic rather than just one method. Remember session != transaction

Comment: This was actually goofing around, but still did lead me to understanding session-per-request pattern. And yes this will be a web app. So my final question would be - should I manage my unit of work by properly configuring isolation and propagation attributes of @Transactional methods, per request to achieve required goals ? I am just trying to put myself into the right mindset.

Comment: @Xeperis It doesn't necessarily have to be done inside `@Transactionals` methods. As I said, a `Session` might span multiple `Transactions`. Look into [`OpenSessionInViewFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)

Comment: Thanks for info. However in my case using JPA and EntityManager it is actually [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html)

Comment: @Xeperis Ah, you are right. I've never used `EntityManager`, I've always gone through Hibernate's stack. Use whichever is appropriate :)